# HTML not finding image

Tags: html, css, image

I am just getting started using HTML and I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.

I am trying to create a basic webpage containing an image that is downloaded when clicked.

So far I have:

`<a href="/images/selfie_img.jpg" download>
    <img src="/images/selfie_img.jpg" alt="Selfie" style="width: 300px">
 </a>`

I expected this to display the image I want as it seems to my eye to be formatted exactly like all the examples I have seen.  However, this only displays the alternative title, not the actual image.

I have checked the image path, and used different images to try and solve the problem.  I am using VS code and the software can follow the image path to find the appropriate image, but when I load the program, the image is replaced by that annoying blue question mark.  Using a URL as the image path seems to work but then the image isn't downloaded when clicked, I just get the URL.

Comment: can you provide the file/folder structure ?

Comment: the images folder is in same directory with your index.html ?

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus I have a directory which contains the python script I am using to create the page (I think that's what it does), as well as the images folder, and the templates folder, within which is the index.html

Comment: @j08691 sorry, I meant to say when you click on the image the browser follows the URL, instead of downloading the image

Comment: If you create an example - then we can be of more help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the question - why doesn't the image show? or - why doesn't the image download? - but I'll also add - that you have a link (inline by default) - with an inline-block element inside of it / and they should probably both be display: block in this case (put some borders on them to see) + https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/xtsb1k7p/

Comment: @sheriffderek The image doesn't show, I believe due to a path issue, because I haven't told the browser the correct place to find the image?  Do I have to create a separate link for the image?  Because when I click where the image should be an html file is downloaded which leads to a 404 error

Comment: The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).

Comment: Also depending on the web server, you might have to declare the full url, or a server url  ( IPAGE hosting does this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, SpicedWater!

The problem you're describing is most likely caused by a wrong path. Your browser resolves the images path and can't find it. I suggest you take a look at the source code in your browser or the developer console's network tab to see what path it's trying to find this image at and which http status code the browser determined.

Comment: I'd confirm that it's the image path: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/xtsb1k7p/

Comment: The HTTP status is 404, and the path is http://localhost:5000/images/selfie_img.jpg

Comment: @SpicedWater please double check your file name and file extension then. If these are correct, go ahead and try an [absolut path instead of an relative](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) one for testing purposes. If both proposals aren't helping my only guess is something related to file ownership or permissions.

Comment: I have used the absolute file path, and the blue question mark is gone, I assume because it has found the image, the new error being "Not allowed to load local resource".  I'm not bothered by this but the image path seems to be right so why couldn't the image be found using the relative image path?

Comment: You mentioned some sort of pythin script above. I guess that's responsible for your issues. If you want to learn just HTML (+ JavaScript & CSS) you don't need to use any scripts or development servers. Just open your HTML document in a browser of your choice.